# Python Relative Import cannot find package

Tags: python, package, directory-structure, relative-import

I'm sure that this is a pretty simple problem and that I am just missing something incredibly obvious, but the answer to this predicament has eluded me for several hours now.

My project directory structure looks like this:

```
-PhysicsMaterial
   -Macros
      __init__.py
      Macros.py
   -Modules
      __init__.py
      AvgAccel.py
      AvgVelocity.py
   -UnitTests
      __init__.py
      AvgAccelUnitTest.py
      AvgVelocityUnitTest.py
    __init__.py
```

Criticisms aside on my naming conventions and directory structure here, I cannot seem to be able to use relative imports. I'm attempting to relative import a Module file to be tested in AvgAccelUnitTest.py:

```
from .Modules import AvgAccel as accel
```

However, I keep getting:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Since I have all of my **init** files set up throughout my structure, and I also have the top directory added to my PYTHONPATH, I am stumped. Why is python not interpreting the package and importing the file correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs because you're running the script as `__main__`.  When you run a script like this:

```
python /path/to/package/module.py
```

That file is loaded as `__main__`, not as `package.module`, so it can't do relative imports because it isn't part of a package.

This can lead to strange errors where a class defined in your script gets defined twice, once as `__main__.Class` and again as `package.module.Class`, which can cause `isinstance` checks to fail and similar oddities.  Because of this, you generally shouldn't run your modules directly.

For your tests, you can remove the `__init__.py` inside the tests directory and just use absolute instead of relative imports.  In fact, your tests probably shouldn't be inside your package at all.

Alternatively, you could create a test runner script that imports your tests and runs them.

Comment: @ Brendan Abel Thanks for the information. After doing a bit more research, I came to the exact same conclusion: ultimately, I ended up using sys.path.append and performing absolute imports. It shouldn't bother me further as I do not intend to be relocating modules within the directory. This actually also solves another import problem involving a function decorator that I needed, so that's two thumbs up!

Comment: You may still run into issues if other modules import the same module you're running on the command line.

Comment: I guess I'll cross that bridge when I come to it. I'm sure by then, I'll have a better solution. This is merely a hobby program with little to no intent to ship, so I think it will turn out alright

Answer (score 0):

[How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Well, guess it's on to using sys.path.append now. Clap and a half to @BrenBarn, @fireant, and @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams